# No templates available for new event and new event template

Tags: civievent, joomla

After installation (Joomla 3.4.8, and civiCRM 4.6.11) , "New event" and "New event template" do not allow entering data as well as they seem not to be able to find the right template.[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like stylesheets aren't loading, so perhaps other resources (like Javascript) aren't either. Double check that the URLs set up in the CiviCRM Resource URLs page match (**Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs**).

[image: Resource URLs]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and suggestion, all the paths seem to be OK

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Finally I decided to clone my installation in another hosting. Everything worked fine. Then, I have decided to leave iPage as ahosting provider. It is clear that iPage does not facilitate working with civiCRM. Thank you very much for your interest.